# How to load image in Viewholder of MovieAdapter?

Tags: java, android, json, universal-image-loader

**Main Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie);
        lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstMovieData);
          moviename.clear();


      //  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        try {
            Title = b.getString("MOVIE");
            t = replace(Title);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        String API = "https://api.cinemalytics.com/v1/movie/title/?value=" + t + "&auth_token=<token>";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        OkHttpClient Client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API).build();
        Call call = Client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
                try {


                    String json = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, json);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                      
                        getDATA(json);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            

                                mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),moviename);
                                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            }

                        });

                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }


            }
        });

  

    }

  

      public String replace(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    }

    private void getDATA(String json) throws JSONException {
           try {

    moviename = new ArrayList<>();
    Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();
    String story = "About The Story";

    JSONArray values = new JSONArray(json);
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);

        String movieTitle = jsonObject.getString("Title");
        String disc = jsonObject.getString("Description");
        Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);
        c= new Currentmovie();
        c.setTitle("Movie Name::"+movieTitle);
        c.setDesc(story+"::\n"+disc);
        if(jsonObject.getString("Description")==null)
        {

            c.setDesc(story+"::Not Available");
        }
        moviename.add(c);

                 } 
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                {
           System.out.println("Error in Result as " + e.toString());
            }

               }
```

**2.MovieAdapter.java**

```
           public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        private List<Currentmovie> movieData;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


        public MovieAdapter( Context context,List<Currentmovie> movieData)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.movieData = movieData;
           inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return movieData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return movieData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public static class ViewHolder{
            public TextView movieTitle,movieDesc;
            public ImageView movieImage;


        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {


            View vi = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.movieTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                holder.movieDesc=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv1);


             vi.setTag( holder );
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();



            holder.movieTitle.setText(movieData.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.movieDesc.setText(movieData.get(position).getDesc());



            return vi;
        }

        }
```

> //i can successfully show all data except image
>
> //image link comes with "posterpath" key
>
> //tell me how to load image in viewholder of MovieAdapter
>
> //currentmovie is just a getter and setter class

**3.Currentmovie.java**

```
public class Currentmovie {

     private String mTitle;
   private String Description;
 

    public String getDesc() {
        return Description;
    }

   public void setDesc(String desc) {
       Description = desc;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `universal image loader library` follow this [link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) ..

Comment: I see that you are parsing APIs by yourself. You can also use their official SDK to do that: https://github.com/Cinemalytics/CinemalyticsJavaSDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library and loading images by

first creating the Display options object by

```
    DisplayImageOptions builder = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.empty_photo)        
                                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_photo)
                                .build();
```

Then initialze the image loader by

```
  ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

and load images by

```
 imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, builder);
```

Hope this helps..
also add this to you gradle

```
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup) first

**EDIT:** Add this to `onCreate()` of activity

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        ...
        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

or this

```
   ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(Activity.this‌​));
```

Comment: bro!!!finally it worked after adding this configuration::  ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(movie.this));(in oncreate)....

Comment: :) :) Thats y i specifically told to check the `Quick Setup` .. I also got stuck on that part.. Anways happy coding :) :) @GIRISHPUROHIT

Comment: There you go mate :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Add getter and setter methods for your Image  like

```
public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

   public void setImageUrl(String imgUrl) {
       imageUrl= imgUrl;
    }
```

Add this code in your adapter class after adding [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to your project:

```
String imageUrl = movieData.get(position).getImageUrl();

Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(holder.movieImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: replace getContext() with context. That is your context variable

Comment: as i understand it loaded image into holder.movieImage and i have done binding in previously process..so i didn;t do any work in onSuccess..plz suggest..

Comment: Did you add the library and all??

Comment: yup i have added using gradle

Comment: What do you mean by you have done binding in previously process?? I didn't get that

Comment: holder.movieImg=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img);

Comment: String imageUrl=movieData.get(position).getImageUrl();

Comment: Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl).resize(50,50).centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.movieImg, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {

Comment: old binding means::  mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),moviename);
                                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: 1.add imageview in row.xml 2.get json imageurl and set to setter class .3.rest changes i have shared with you in last 3-4 comments.                       Anything else??

Comment: Try debugging and check whether you are getting the image url and check whether the url contains data

Comment: i have checked i am getting the image url(in log),when click on url it shows the picture also